# Creating directory

Tags: java, file-io, directory

I am trying to create a directory in Java.

I am proceeding as follows:

```
File a = new File("../dirA/dirB/dirC");
```

Where dirA exists, but dirB and dirC don't. I then run:

```
a.mkdir();
```

Hoping this would also create dirB but, apparently, it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) instead, it will create all parent directories.

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories.

Answer (score 1):

you need to exchange `mkdir` for `mkdirs`.
This question coul've been easily answered if you had looked at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir())